# Someone else's lock on my bike

Tags: lock, theft

Earlier today, I had to leave my bike in the street to run some errands. Just after I was done attaching it to a barrier, a person came to me and asked me about my kryptonite lock as he was locking his own bike next to mine (it sounds mundane, but it's what got me thinking). When I came back a few minutes later, he had locked his bike to mine in addition to the barrier as you can see here:

[image]

I waited for him for a while but he didn't show up and I needed to go back to work so I left. To my knowledge, there are two options:

1. he did it on purpose so he could come back later to steal my bike (but in this case why did he engage me at all?)
2. he did it by mistake and is eventually coming back for his bike (preferably by the end of the day)

Should I just go 'fuck this guy's bike', rent an angle grinder and cut open the lock?

Additional informations: it's a quiet street, the barrier is in front of an elementary school and the police was no help at all as they told me they don't recommend damaging someone else's property, but that I would probably not get in trouble for doing so in that case.

Comment: The chipped paint on his bike makes me believe that this is a careless person who made a simple mistake (your option 2). I think the right thing is to wait a day and hope he comes back and unlocks it. There is a very small chance that they have registered the frame number and you can get a phone number from the police.

Comment: The other bike is somewhat more valuable than yours based on new pricing. It looks very much like a careless mistake, though very irritating. You will have to exercise some patience and forgiveness!

Comment: I'd sure put additional locks on your bike to secure your wheels, as they seem to be easily removable.

Comment: Call "The Lock picking Lawyer". But, seriously, a capable locksmith may be able to open the other person's lock without destroying it, and re-lock the other person's bike. You may need to provide proof of ownership of your bike, though, so the locksmith knows they're not actually helping you steal a bike.

Comment: Which bike is yours?

Comment: Whatever you do, *don't* reposition *your own lock* so it also locks *his* bike to yours!

Comment: I have done that, so...

Comment: @shoover the one that has two locks attached to it

Comment: @Jahaziel only that, the fee for locksmith will be most likely more expensive than the bike is worth.

Comment: "...but in this case why did he engage me at all?"
Here's an interesting idea: to establish an alibi for something else. In Higashino Keigo's novel _The Devotion of Suspect X,_ the murderer wanted to make it look as if the crime was committed one night later than it actually was. As part of this, he steals an old beat-up bike that was secured with a chain, despite their being several newer unsecured bikes at the railway station, as _he need to be sure that the owner would report it to the police._ (He used the bike to move the body, then dumps the body and bike, to establish the fake date).

Comment: I had once done it to a guy in my college days. The look on his face when I came back to unlock it was priceless.

Comment: I need closure. What happened?

Comment: @Duncan He's still waiting.

Comment: @Duncan here => https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/84320/someone-elses-lock-on-my-bike?noredirect=1#comment198658_84336

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Another option if you're planning on cutting the lock, and don't want to leave their bike unlocked:

- Rent cutting tool and remove your bike
- Lock the other bike with your lock
- Find a good hiding place for the key somewhere near (or find a friendly store that will remain open and ask if they can hold on to the key)
- Leave a note on their bike explaining what happened and with your number to text you so you'll tell them where the key is
- Use your bike to go buy a new lock for yourself lol
- When someone texts you, ask them to identify themselves by asking them to describe what their lock used to look like. After someone identifies themselves correctly, give out the location (or send them an elaborate treasure map)

If you don't want to donate your lock

- find a place nearby that is willing to hold on to their bike
- leave a similar note for them to text you to get the location of the bike

Also, if you really want to, you could try asking them to send you an electronic payment (cash app, venmo, paypal, crypto, etc) to cover the cost of the lock and the cutting tool rental, before you give out the location

Comment: I'm going with this answer. I like the idea of not leaving someone else's bike unattended. For those who are looking for some closure: in the end I didn't have to do anything. When I got back to my bike, the person was just hanging there. He apologized profusely and offered me a meal at his restaurant as compensation. A friend told me that the whole thing was in fact a ruse to get me to have dinner with him and I don't know what to believe anymore.

Comment: What a plot twist. Sounds like a very effective pickup technique lol

Comment: Effective if you think starting off a relationship by really pissing off a total stranger is a good idea.  I do find it highly implausible just from the photo that someone could have done that by accident though.  Maybe a chain/cable lock you could make that mistake, but you'd have to be next-level absentminded to not see the other bike inside the U-bolt style locks.

Comment: First he controls your bike, then he controls your life. Sounds like a real sonofabitch.

Comment: I'm going to be charitable and say the guy was trying to engineer a "meet cute". He's just seen too many rom-coms.

Comment: I would add one more step first - take clear photos of the double-locked bikes including a wider location shot, in case there is any later dispute over why you cut off the lock.  OP clearly has the photo included but for anyone else reading the answer this would be a good precaution.

Comment: But did you have dinner with them!? @Dorian Don't leave us hanging XD

Comment: @NateW, I'm still on the fence about this. He was kinda shady, but… a free meal's a free meal.

Comment: @Dorian if looking back at it years from now, it turns out to have been a life defining event, please make sure to let us know lol

Comment: @Dorian Yeah, if he ends up stealing your *heart* please report back, so we can add this to our list of bike scams to watch out for...

Answer (score 22):

I've heard of this being a tactic to encourage you to accidentally leave your bike unlocked, so they can come back and steal your bike later, but on balance it could just as well be accidental.

If you think it's the former, then cut their lock and leave it behind.

If it's just a mistake, then waiting it out is inconvenient but the polite answer.  Supporting this is that your bike isn't a fancy race bike and probably doesn't have a high value to a thief, and that if redbike-rider was standing on the far side of barrier, they might not have even seen your greybike's top tube for the black barrier in the way.

Yes, it's really annoying, but "never attribute to malice that which is explained by stupidity" or [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).

Comment: It's not that the thieves who employ this tactic are trying to get you to leave your bike unlocked. They're hoping to wait it out and come back at 2 am when the victim and no one else is around.

Comment: @PaulH Why would the victim be around at 2a.m.?

Comment: @Michael that's worded poorly. The victim isn't around. "No one else, including the victim, is around" is a better way (still awkward though)

Comment: @PaulH Still not sure I understand... are they hoping the victim removes their lock and then leaves before 2a.m.? Which seems to be what the first sentence is implying.

Comment: No. They're hoping the victim and all other crowds leave. Then at 2 am, they can cut the victim's lock with relatively little risk of getting caught.

Comment: In other words, if you rely on your bike for transportation, you're not going to wait around forever for someone to remove their lock from yours. You have to be a work in the morning, so you assume good faith, take a bus home, and figure you can come back for you bike in the morning. Only overnight, the thief unlocked their bike, and then cut the lock on your bike to steal it.

Comment: @PaulH ah gotcha... them cutting *your* lock is the part I was missing.

Comment: I agree, this looks very hard to do by mistake. Assuming that your bike is worth stealing, I think this is a tactic to get you to leave it overnight.

Answer (score 10):

Destroy the offending lock.  You are wasting time and energy worrying about his feelings when it was his mistake that cost you time and money.

Comment: It can be a good thing to be kind to others even when others make mistakes. When the time comes that it is you the one who makes a mistake, you would likely prefer that people still try to look out for you as opposed to not

Comment: I'm willing to lose a lock over a dumb mistake.

Comment: @Kaz I think the worry wasn't that much about the lock, but instead about leaving the bike unlocked, so potentially losing a bike not just losing a lock

Answer (score 6):

Your options are:

1. Wait it out
2. Cut/break/grind the lock

Those are the only two reasonable options I can think of.

I would wait it out unless there is some compelling reason to damage the lock and leave the other bike unlocked.